# Error on deploying Java EE 6 on WAS7

Tags: websphere-7

I'm trying to deploy an EJB 3 EAR project to WebSphere 7.

From RSA 8.0 I select the EAR file. When I select the EAR project > run as > Server > WAS7 I get the following error:

*"the server does not support version 6.0 of the J2EE Enterprise application specification"*

I changed my JRE/JDK to 1.5 in RSA, but the same thing happens. Is it a specific jar which causes this>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java EE versions (J2EE 1.3, J2EE 1.4, Java EE 5, Java EE 6) are not the same like JRE/JDK version, this are two different things.

- JRE/JDK is about the language, compiler and the java core frameworks.
- J2EE/Java EE is about high level frameworks like EJB, JPA, JSF, CDI....

---

WebSphere Application Server 7 supports (only) Java EE 5 but not Java EE 6.
So you need to build a Java EE 5 application, reducing JRE/JDK from 6 to 5 is not enough, you also need to build a Java EE 5 EAR, without usage of any of the great Java EE 6 features.

So if it is only for your own, then I recommend to use GlassFish v3 instead, it has Java EE 6 support.

Comment: Thanks, its because i created the EAR project on eclipse STS IDE which defaults to JEE6. Importing it to WAS7 would need me to choose JEE5